# Why does my USB3 start fast and then slow down? - windows 10

Tags: window, usb-3

I started a transfer of a file to my USB stick - it started at around 50-100MB/s and then dropped down to ~15MB/s for the most part.

Why would this be and what can I do about it?

[image: s]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The USB drive probably has a high-speed cache (50+ MB/s writing). When this small cache is full, the drive writes to slower flash memory.

Comment: Do you mean it could be an issue with the USB stick itself? (and not the PC?) - I could test that with some other sticks I guess : )

Comment: Yes, it's very likely that it's just a slow USB stick.

Comment: I think this is rather the memory cache of Windows - reading into memory is fast, but when it fills up writing is slow.

Comment: @harrymc is there anything to be done about that?

Comment: Only getting a faster stick. One that supports USB 3, or even USB 3.1 if you have the right port.

Comment: What is a high-speed cache for USB sticks and how could it be useful?